# Connected countable dense homogeneous space is homogeneous.

Tags: general-topology, homogeneous-spaces

For a topological space $X$,

- $\mathcal{H}(X)$ denotes the set of all autohomeomorphism of $X$. Note that, with the composition of functions,  $(\mathcal{H}(X),\circ)$ is a group with identity $\mbox{Id}_{X}$.
- If $x\in X$, let $\mathcal{O}(x,X)=\{h(x):h\in\mathcal{H}(X)\}$, we call this set the **orbit** of $x$ (under homeomorphism). Note that $x=\mbox{Id}_{X}(x)\in \mathcal{O}(x,X)$.
- Note that for each $x\in X$, $\mathcal{O}(x,X)$ is fixed under autohomeomorphisms of $X$ (that is, for each $h\in\mathcal{H}(X)$, $h[\mathcal{O}(x,X)]=\mathcal{O}(x,X)$)

A topological space $X$ is called **countable dense homogeneous** if

1. $X$ is separable, and
2. for any pair $D, E$ of countable dense subsets there exists $h\in\mathcal{H}(X)$ such that $h[D]=E$.

A topological space $X$ is **homogeneous** if for every $x, y \in X$ there is $h\in \mathcal{H}(X)$ such that $h(x) = y$.

The motivation for this question is to demonstrate the following claim

- **Every connected countable dense homogeneous space is homogeneous.**

For this, we follow the following preliminary steps

1. For every $x\in X$, $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x,X)}$ is a clopen subset of $X$.
2. If $x,y\in X$ are such that $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x,X)}\cap \overline{\mathcal{O}(y,X)}\not=\emptyset$, then $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x,X)}=\overline{\mathcal{O}(y,X)}$.
3. Let $x\in X$, then $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x,X)}$ is a countable dense homogeneous space.
4. Let $x\in X$, then $\overline{\mathcal{O}(x,X)}=\mathcal{O}(x,X)$.

Finally, let $X$ be a connected countable dense homogeneous space and let $x,y\in X$. Note that $\mathcal{O}(x, X)$ and $\mathcal{O}(y, X)$ are clopen, also are non-empty sets. Then $\mathcal{O}(x, X)=\mathcal{O}(y, X)=X$. Therefore there is $h\in\mathcal{H}(X)$ such that $h(x)=y$.

Unfortunately I just couldn't prove step 4, someone has a suggestion on how to prove that, or some other new suggestion to directly prove the claim.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the meaning of the sentence "Every connected countable dense homogeneous space is homogeneous"?  It sounds like a tautology.  Dense where?  Are you using a non-standard meaning of the word "dense"?

Comment: @Ruy: A space $X$ is *countable dense homogeneous* (CDH) if for any two countable, dense subsets $D$ and $E$ of $X$ there is an autohomeomorphism $f$ of $X$ such that $f[D]=E$. I believe that they were first studied by Ralph Bennett in a $1972$ paper in *Fundamenta Mathematicae*.

Comment: Well, thanks for the observation, I just edited the question, In fact, @Brian Scott, in this paper, there is a proof in the case, for $X$ first countable.

Comment: @user987: Take a look at the theorem in section $3$ of [this PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.588.5546&rep=rep1&type=pdf); I didn’t check the proof, but it appears to prove a generalization of the result that you want.

Comment: Hi @Brian, thanks for the definition.  I was taken aback because elementary concepts such as orbit were carefully defined, but CDH wasn't.

Comment: Thanks for the information @BrianM.Scott, I'll start working on it right away.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of a first countable space we have that:

[image]
[image]